# Is it safe to use an Outputstream created from one thread in another?

Tags: java, multithreading, scala

In my scala code, I am creating a GzipOutputStream object from my main function, and using it in a future, which is called in each loop. Before starting the future in an iteration, the future of the previous iteration is waited for. So, the GzipOutputStream object is never simultaneously accessed by different threads. However, I've noticed that the program is generating corrupt zip files sometimes. So, my question is, is it safe to use a GzipOutputStream object from different threads, if not done simultaenously?

Basically, following is the pseducode

```
gzos = new GzipOutputStream(...)
....
for loop:
  f = future(futureFunction)
  ....
  waitFor(f)
gzos.close

def futureFunction(...)
  ...
  gzos.write(...)
  ...
```

Comment: If you declare it as final or volatile, then it is safe. I bet the corrupt zip files have other cause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GzipOutputStream` is a stateful object. It's not enough just to run tasks one after another. For a proper work you need the changes made by the first iteration be visible to a thread which performs the second iteration.
Basically you need a relation 'end of the first iteration' HAPPENS BEFORE 'start of the second iteration'.

I'm not sure whether this relation holds in general for arbitrary execution context.
But if you use for example single threaded execution context it is obviously true.

Comment: Yes the first iteration always happen before the second iteration in my code, as you can see from the pseudo code I've given. Basically, the n+1 future would always starting executing after the end of n future.

Comment: I mean `happens before` as a JVM concept (https://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/jsr-133-faq.html). By default there is no guarantee that one thread can see the changes done by another thread even if you know that they run one after another.

Comment: Also in the beginning of `futureFunction` you can add `gzos.synchronized(())`.

Answer (score 0):

You may find akka-streams a good fit for this problem.

```
import akka.stream.scaladsl._
import akka.stream._

implicit val system = ActorSystem()
implicit val mat = ActorMaterializer()

val runnable: Future[IOResult] =
    Source(1 to 10)
    .mapAsync(1)(i => Future.successful(i))
    .map(s => ByteString(s + "\n"))
    .via(Compression.gzip)
    .runWith(FileIO.toPath(Paths.get("out.gz")))

val result = Await.result(runnable, 10.seconds)
```

for more see http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/scala/stream/stream-quickstart.html